# Pocket Cube (2x2x2 Rubik's cube) as Quotient Group

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group, gap, rubiks-cube

The 2x2x2 Rubik's cube (also called Pocket cube) consists of $6 \cdot 4 = 24$ small squares. A rotation of one of the faces of the cube can therefore be described as an element of $S_{24}$ (giving every square a number and checking how they move when we do a rotation of one of the faces). In GAP we could define these rotations (that generate all possible manipulations) as

```
gap> U := (1,2,3,4)(5,17,13,9)(6,18,14,10);
gap> L := (5,6,7,8)(1,9,21,19)(4,12,24,18);
gap> R := (13,14,15,16)(2,20,22,10)(3,17,23,11);  
gap> F := (9,10,11,12)(4,13,22,7)(3,16,21,6);
gap> B := (17,18,19,20)(1,8,23,14)(2,5,24,15);
gap> D := (21,22,23,24)(11,15,19,7)(12,16,20,8);
```

If we now define the pocket cube as the subgroup of $S_{24}$ that is generated by these elements we get a subgroup of size $88179840=2^7 \cdot 3^9 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$:

```
gap> fullCube := Group(U,L,R,F,B,D);
gap> Print(Size(fullCube));
88179840
```

It is, however, well known that the pocket cube only has $3674160=2^4 \cdot 3^8 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$ different positions. The thing that went wrong is that rotating the full cube yields (in our eyes) the same cube. However, in the group `fullCube` it would be a different position. Hence, the idea is to consider the subgroup generated by these "full rotations".

```
gap> x := (5,8,7,6)(1,19,21,9)(2,20,22,10)(3,17,23,11)(4,18,24,12)(13,14,15,16); # turn front to top
gap> y := (1,2,3,4)(5,17,13,9)(6,18,14,10)(7,19,15,11)(8,20,16,12)(21,24,23,22); # turn right to front
gap> z := (8,1,14,23)(5,2,15,24)(7,4,13,22)(6,3,16,21)(9,10,11,12)(17,20,19,18); # turn top to right 
gap> rotations := Group(x,y,z);
gap> Print(Size(rotations));
24
```

This looks good as the subgroup of rotations has $24=2^3 \cdot 3$ elements. So, if we factor `fullCube` by `rotations` we should get exactly the group we are looking for with the $3674160=88179840/24$ elements. Two elements in the group `fullCube` would be considered equal if and only if they represent the same position (without regarding the rotation of the entire cube). Let's try this and first check whether `rotations` is really a normal subgroup of `fullCube`:

```
gap> Print(IsNormal(fullCube, rotations));
false
```

Surprise (at least for me...), this is not a normal subgroup. So, we cannot consider the quotient group...

This construction seems like the most natural approach for constructing the group. Why does this fail? Is there a way to fix it and still define the pocket cube group as a quotient group?

Note that a different way to define the group would be to consider one of the corner pieces fixed and therefore only consider certain face rotations which generated the group:

```
gap> cube := Group(U,L,B); # cube where bottom right cubie is fixed 
gap> Print(Size(cube));
3674160
```

This does work and yields the right group. It is, however, to me, not as intuitive as the other approach.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but the way I think about the `fullCube` you defined is to pretend it's a Pocket cube but with center squares, ie a regular Rubik's cube but with no edge pieces.  That way it becomes clear that an algorithm like $RL'$ produces a new element, whereas in the usual Pocket cube group this is just a solved cube.

Comment: If you conjugate a move by a rotation, then you get another move. However, for the rotations to be a normal group, you'd need a rotation conjugated by a move to be another rotation.